# Remove matched characters from array values if it's on last position of sentance

Tags: replace

Following one is an example string array:

```
$stringArrr=array("This is demo=20",
"This is example value=20", 
"This is last =20 line of my string"
);
```

I am trying to remove  =20 at end of each index value from $stringArrr.

But while I am using php str_replace it's remove all =20 from $stringArrr

```
$stringArrr=str_replace("=20",'',$stringArrr);
```

Output of the array:

```
  array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "This is demo"
  [1]=>
  string(21) "This is example value"
  [2]=>
  string(31) "This is last  line of my string"
  }
```

But I want output like following one:

```
  array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "This is demo"
  [1]=>
  string(21) "This is example value"
  [2]=>
  string(31) "This is last =20 line of my string"
  }
```

I am new in php, please provide solved scripts for above issue.

Thanks advance for your help.

Comment: please format the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of **str_replace** use **preg_replace** using following regular expression as follow:

```
$stringArrr=preg_replace('/=20$/i','',$stringArrr);
```